# contentsOfDirectoryAtPath returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, null, nsbundle

I have a folder with  a bunch of images named “Pictures” right inside “Supporting Files”, but when I try to retrieve the files it returns nil, even though I'm sure there are images inside; I try to do it with the following code inside `viewDidLoad()`

```
let sourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Pictures")
let imgArray = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(sourcePath, error: nil)
```

And when I do this: `println(imgArray)` it always prints nil.

Why?? And what should I do?

Comment: println `sourcePath` and verify the file exists there with the finder if in the simulator or Xcode on a device. Simply it does not exist where you think it is or with the name you expect or at all.

Comment: What I really do not understand: If the function does not return what you expect, and the function has an `error` parameter, why don't you *use* that parameter and print the error in the case of a failure?

Comment: Have a look at your "copy resources" build phase and see if the images really are being added into a "Pictures" subfolder within the bundle.

Comment: Yes, I can see all the photos in "Copy Bundle Resources", I can't see the folder though. But what does this mean? And yes, I'm sure the files exists, I can see the folder inside my project folder in Finder.

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it work! :D

I added the folder directly in "Copy Bundle Resources" with the "+" button and now it properly returns an array containing the images. Thanks to Abizem who pointed out the copy bundle resources...